# How can I make the bot send a message along with an image? (Without the link and without using embed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

How can I make the bot send a message with an image below it? (Just the image; without the link) By using the default `message.channel.send()` and not through an embed. The code below is what I have at the moment.

```
message.channel.send("Hello", "https://imgur.com/gallery/XXXXXXX");
```

Comment: Have you tried sending base64 encoded image data instead of URL ? 
Try this https://www.base64-image.de/ for testing, later on you can build the encoder on your own(it's a few lines of code). Put the resulting base64  data in <img>'s src attribute See if it works.
PS: Try using smaller image for testing.

Answer (score 1):

In [this part of the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), specifically the second code snippet, it shows how to attach an image from a remote URL to a message. You can use the same format as it then shows in the fourth snippet to add it to the text. It should end up something like this.

```js
message.channel.send("Hello", { 
    files: ["https://imgur.com/gallery/XXXXXXX"],
});
```